# Error regarding AjaxControlToolKit

Tags: asp.net, ajaxcontroltoolkit

When I run a page I get the following parse error.

> Parser Error
>
> Description: An error occurred during the parsing of a resource required to service this request. Please review the following specific parse error details and modify your source file appropriately.
>
> Parser Error Message: Could not load file or assembly 'AjaxControlToolkit, Version=1.0.10618.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=28f01b0e84b6d53e' or one of its dependencies. The located assembly's manifest definition does not match the assembly reference. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80131040)
>
> Source Error:
>
> Line 1:  <%@ Page Language="vb" AutoEventWireup="false" CodeBehind="AppointmentSchedule.aspx.vb" Inherits="AFKLogin.AppointmentSchedule" MasterPageFile="~/Login/PatientMaster.Master" %>
>
> Line 2:
>
> Line 3:  <%@ Register Assembly="AjaxControlToolkit" Namespace="AjaxControlToolkit" TagPrefix="cc1" %>
>
> Source File: /Allforkids/Login/AppointmentSchedule.aspx    Line: 1
>
> Assembly Load Trace: The following information can be helpful to determine why the assembly 'AjaxControlToolkit, Version=1.0.10618.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=28f01b0e84b6d53e' could not be loaded.
>
> WRN: Assembly binding logging is turned OFF.
>   To enable assembly bind failure logging, set the registry value [HKLM\Software\Microsoft\Fusion!EnableLog] (DWORD) to 1.
>   Note: There is some performance penalty associated with assembly bind failure logging.
>   To turn this feature off, remove the registry value [HKLM\Software\Microsoft\Fusion!EnableLog].
>
> Version Information: Microsoft .NET Framework Version:2.0.50727.3082; ASP.NET Version:2.0.50727.3082

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 0):

Are you using version 1.0 or 3.0 of the AjaxControlToolkit? You may have accidentally referenced the 1.0 version when you shouldn't have.

Comment: We are running ASP.Net version 2.0.Means visualstudio 2005.So which version of AjaxToolKit i hve to refer?Here iam using AjaxControlToolKit 1.0

Comment: I would enable assembly binding logging as suggested.